# Is there anything similar to c2dm, to get know user position or I need to implement service and inform server periodically?

Tags: android

I need to inform user with location specific data from server when they are on some location. Is there anything similar to c2dm, to get know user position or I need to implement service and inform server periodically ?

Comment: I don't understand how the server will know the user's position. What has this got to do with c2dm?

Answer (score 1):

you can set a variable true or false.Use c2dm to activate this variable from server side...when this variable change his state then it means that server want your position, and you send it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking if there is a service which has all user positions saved and up-to-date. That is not the case (at least nothing like that officially exists). You will need to get the data from the gps sensor and then compare it periodically with the server data.

Comment: Well techically the mobile phone operators have access to that information although it's obviously not publically available and the location accuracy could easily be 1000 metres out.

Comment: @MisterSquonk do you know if there is no possible way to access that user location information, even passively?  What I mean is maybe sending a C2DM or other push message and have Google or some other service reject or accept the message based on the users location.  I am trying to create this feature without having to have a service running all the time and polling location and sending that to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't generally use C2DM to request data from the user.

It sounds like when you go near a location, the server needs to supply the client with data about that location?

If so, you could use C2DM to give the user a list of locations of interest. Then when the client goes near it, they request the data from the server.
Depending on how often these locations change (and the importance if they do..) determine if C2DM is worth implementing.

If the updates are only important to the user when using the app, request the list of locations on app start up / periodically when the app is in use / refresh button.

If they don't update often, but the user is going to want to be warned without using the app (natural disaster or something), use C2DM

If they update at set times (hourly, daily etc), use a service to pull the updates at those times / intervals.